# Twilio Twiml refuse to say dynamic text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am getting crazy trying to understand what is wrong with twilio. I have this twiml (just an example):

http://twilio.gomme-auto.it/twilio/order/address/check/208325

```
<Response>
<Say voice="man" language="it">gomme auto punto i t.</Say>
<Say voice="man" language="it">
per il tuo ordine numero due zero otto tre due cinque.
</Say>
<Say voice="man" language="it">
vogliamo verificare l'indirizzo di destinazione. L'indirizzo inserito è:
</Say>
<Say voice="man" language="it">Via Amedeo Modigliani 1,</Say>
<Say voice="man" language="it">Curtatone.</Say>
<Say voice="man" language="it">Il CAP inserito è quattro sei zero uno zero.</Say>
<Gather numDigits="1" action="http://twilio.gomme-auto.it/twilio/order/address/check/208325/">
<Say voice="man" language="it">Per confermare l'indirizzo inserito, premi 1.</Say>
<Say voice="man" language="it">Per modificare l'indirizzo, premi 2.</Say>
<Say voice="man" language="it">Per riascoltare l'indirizzo, premi 3.</Say>
</Gather>
</Response>
```

Where "Say" lines 2 and 4,5,6 are generated dynamically, the others are static text.

I am using Twilio.MVC official library and generating the Twiml like this:

```
  var response = new TwilioResponse();
  var voice = new { voice = "man", language = "it" };
    response.Say("gomme auto punto i t.", voice);
    response.Say("per il tuo ordine numero " + twu.Dictable(cart.crt.cartid.ToString()) + ".", voice);
    response.Say("vogliamo verificare l'indirizzo di destinazione. L'indirizzo inserito è: ", voice);
```

Every single line with a static text is said correctly, the others are ignored.

We didn't change anything in the code, and it was working till a week ago...

If anyone had an idea about what it could be it would be great.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. One thing I can see immediately is that you have one too many closing brackets on line 4. It should read response.Say("per il tuo ordine numero " + twu.Dictable(cart.crt.cartid.ToString() + ".", voice);

Comment: Thanks Marcos, that was just a typo in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer from Twilio support, it's a bug on their side, only the standard "man" voice is affected. Changing to "alice" I got it working again.